# Gmail Setting Issue only my gmail account

Tags: gmail, settings

In my gmail account I want to add signature with image but did not get option for this but in other account of gmail there is option to add a signature with image.
I don't know what is problem with my own account.

need solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this link

[How to Make Cool Gmail Signatures Right from Google Drive](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/make-cool-gmail-signatures-right-google-drive/)

[how-to-create-a-signature-with-your-logo-in-gmail](https://www.logomaker.com/blog/2012/07/11/how-to-create-a-signature-with-your-logo-in-gmail/)

[Use Google Drive to host your Gmail signature](http://gappstips.com/gmail/use-google-drive-to-host-your-gmail-signature/)